# XQuery to return name of Unicode block?

Tags: unicode, xquery

I have an XQuery that returns the distinct set of characters from my input directory that are not in the BasicLatin unicode block. Rather than return the characters themselves, I would like the query to return the name of the unicode block they're in (e.g. "Latin-1 Supplement" rather than, as currently,  "ä" (a umlaut)). Is there a way to do that?

```
xquery version "1.0";
declare namespace ead = "urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9";
declare default element namespace "urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9";
declare copy-namespaces no-preserve, inherit;

import module namespace functx="http://www.functx.com" 
at "http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xq";


declare variable $COLL as document-node()+ := collection("[input_url]");

let $non-BasicLatin_all := $COLL//text()[matches(., '\P{IsBasicLatin}')]
let $non-BasicLatin_item :=
    for $x in $non-BasicLatin_all
    return functx:get-matches($x, '\P{IsBasicLatin}')  
let $distinct_character := 
    for $x in distinct-values($non-BasicLatin_item)
    return <character>{$x}</character>

return
<characters distinct-count="{count($distinct_character)}">
{$distinct_character}
</characters>
```

Comment: What do you mean with the "name of the block". What is a block? Do you mean an element?

Comment: Are you sure that your XQuery implementation supports the `\P{IsBasicLatin}` regex expression? Which implementation are you using? As to your sample code, does it work, or if not, what error do you get?

Comment: Sorry not to have been clearer. By "name of the block" I mean "BasicLatin", "Latin-1Supplement", etc.

Comment: The XQuery I posted works fine, but it's not quite what I want. It returns special characters that are not in the BasicLatin block. What I actually want is the name of the unicode block they're in, not the characters themselves. So whereas my query currently might return "ä" (a umlaut), what I would want it to return in that case is "Latin-1 Supplement".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct functionality in XQuery to do so. You will have to resolve to codepoints of the characters and find a database to resolve to the unicode blocks on your own, probably an XML document would be best fit.

Resolving code points can be achieved using `string-to-codepoints('漢字')`, which will return a sequence of integers.

Comment: Thanks Jens, that's exactly what I needed--I wasn't aware of string-to-codepoints.

Answer (score 1):

XML versions of the Unicode character set database are available from [the Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/versions/); both the flat and the grouped versions of the data contain a list of blocks with the following form:

```
<blocks>
  <block first-cp="0000" last-cp="007F" name="Basic Latin"/>
  <block first-cp="0080" last-cp="00FF" name="Latin-1 Supplement"/>
  <block first-cp="0100" last-cp="017F" name="Latin Extended-A"/>
  <block first-cp="0180" last-cp="024F" name="Latin Extended-B"/>
  ...
  <block first-cp="2F800" last-cp="2FA1F" name="CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement"/>
  <block first-cp="E0000" last-cp="E007F" name="Tags"/>
  <block first-cp="E0100" last-cp="E01EF" name="Variation Selectors Supplement"/>
  <block first-cp="F0000" last-cp="FFFFF" name="Supplementary Private Use Area-A"/>
  <block first-cp="100000" last-cp="10FFFF" name="Supplementary Private Use Area-B"/>
</blocks>
```

Write a function to accept a character, consult the block ranges in the database (converting them from hex to decimal for comparison), and return the name of the block (or its block element).  If speed becomes an issue, make a copy of the block list and do the hex-to-decimal conversions once for all.

Note that some block names and some block boundaries have changed over the life of Unicode; you'll need to decide which version of the database you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else may find this useful, here's what I came up with based on Jens Erat's and C.M. Sperberg-McQueer's suggestions (using Unicode 6.3.0):

```
xquery version "1.0";
declare namespace ead = "urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9";
declare default element namespace "urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9";
declare copy-namespaces no-preserve, inherit;

import module namespace functx="http://www.functx.com" 
at "http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xq";


declare variable $COLL as document-node()+ := collection("[input_directory]");

let $non-BasicLatin_all := $COLL//text()[matches(., '\P{IsBasicLatin}')]
let $non-BasicLatin_item :=
    for $x in $non-BasicLatin_all
    return functx:get-matches($x, '\P{IsBasicLatin}')  
let $distinct_character := 
    for $x in distinct-values($non-BasicLatin_item)
    order by $x
    return 
    if($x[not(.='')])
    then string-to-codepoints($x)
    else()
let $block-name :=
    for $x in distinct-values($distinct_character)
    return
    if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 0, 127)) then "Basic Latin"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 128, 255)) then "Latin-1 Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 256, 383)) then "Latin Extended-A"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 384, 591)) then "Latin Extended-B"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 592, 687)) then "IPA Extensions"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 688, 767)) then "Spacing Modifier Letters"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 768, 879)) then "Combining Diacritical Marks"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 880, 1023)) then "Greek and Coptic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 1024, 1279)) then "Cyrillic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 1280, 1327)) then "Cyrillic Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 1328, 1423)) then "Armenian"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 1424, 1535)) then "Hebrew"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 1536, 1791)) then "Arabic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 1792, 1871)) then "Syriac"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 1872, 1919)) then "Arabic Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 1920, 1983)) then "Thaana"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 1984, 2047)) then "NKo"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 2048, 2111)) then "Samaritan"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 2112, 2143)) then "Mandaic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 2208, 2303)) then "Arabic Extended-A"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 2304, 2431)) then "Devanagari"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 2432, 2559)) then "Bengali"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 2560, 2687)) then "Gurmukhi"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 2688, 2815)) then "Gujarati"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 2816, 2943)) then "Oriya"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 2944, 3071)) then "Tamil"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 3072, 3199)) then "Telugu"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 3200, 3327)) then "Kannada"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 3328, 3455)) then "Malayalam"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 3456, 3583)) then "Sinhala"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 3584, 3711)) then "Thai"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 3712, 3839)) then "Lao"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 3840, 4095)) then "Tibetan"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 4096, 4255)) then "Myanmar"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 4256, 4351)) then "Georgian"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 4352, 4607)) then "Hangul Jamo"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 4608, 4991)) then "Ethiopic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 4992, 5023)) then "Ethiopic Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 5024, 5119)) then "Cherokee"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 5120, 5759)) then "Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 5760, 5791)) then "Ogham"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 5792, 5887)) then "Runic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 5888, 5919)) then "Tagalog"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 5920, 5951)) then "Hanunoo"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 5952, 5983)) then "Buhid"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 5984, 6015)) then "Tagbanwa"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 6016, 6143)) then "Khmer"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 6144, 6319)) then "Mongolian"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 6320, 6399)) then "Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics Extended"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 6400, 6479)) then "Limbu"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 6480, 6527)) then "Tai Le"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 6528, 6623)) then "New Tai Lue"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 6624, 6655)) then "Khmer Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 6656, 6687)) then "Buginese"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 6688, 6831)) then "Tai Tham"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 6912, 7039)) then "Balinese"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 7040, 7103)) then "Sundanese"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 7104, 7167)) then "Batak"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 7168, 7247)) then "Lepcha"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 7248, 7295)) then "Ol Chiki"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 7360, 7375)) then "Sundanese Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 7376, 7423)) then "Vedic Extensions"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 7424, 7551)) then "Phonetic Extensions"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 7552, 7615)) then "Phonetic Extensions Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 7616, 7679)) then "Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 7680, 7935)) then "Latin Extended Additional"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 7936, 8191)) then "Greek Extended"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 8192, 8303)) then "General Punctuation"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 8304, 8351)) then "Superscripts and Subscripts"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 8352, 8399)) then "Currency Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 8400, 8447)) then "Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 8448, 8527)) then "Letterlike Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 8528, 8591)) then "Number Forms"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 8592, 8703)) then "Arrows"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 8704, 8959)) then "Mathematical Operators"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 8960, 9215)) then "Miscellaneous Technical"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 9216, 9279)) then "Control Pictures"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 9280, 9311)) then "Optical Character Recognition"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 9312, 9471)) then "Enclosed Alphanumerics"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 9472, 9599)) then "Box Drawing"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 9600, 9631)) then "Block Elements"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 9632, 9727)) then "Geometric Shapes"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 9728, 9983)) then "Miscellaneous Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 9984, 10175)) then "Dingbats"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 10176, 10223)) then "Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-A"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 10224, 10239)) then "Supplemental Arrows-A"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 10240, 10495)) then "Braille Patterns"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 10496, 10623)) then "Supplemental Arrows-B"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 10624, 10751)) then "Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-B"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 10752, 11007)) then "Supplemental Mathematical Operators"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 11008, 11263)) then "Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 11264, 11359)) then "Glagolitic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 11360, 11391)) then "Latin Extended-C"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 11392, 11519)) then "Coptic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 11520, 11567)) then "Georgian Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 11568, 11647)) then "Tifinagh"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 11648, 11743)) then "Ethiopic Extended"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 11744, 11775)) then "Cyrillic Extended-A"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 11776, 11903)) then "Supplemental Punctuation"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 11904, 12031)) then "CJK Radicals Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12032, 12255)) then "Kangxi Radicals"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12272, 12287)) then "Ideographic Description Characters"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12288, 12351)) then "CJK Symbols and Punctuation"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12352, 12447)) then "Hiragana"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12448, 12543)) then "Katakana"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12544, 12591)) then "Bopomofo"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12592, 12687)) then "Hangul Compatibility Jamo"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12688, 12703)) then "Kanbun"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12704, 12735)) then "Bopomofo Extended"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12736, 12783)) then "CJK Strokes"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12784, 12799)) then "Katakana Phonetic Extensions"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 12800, 13055)) then "Enclosed CJK Letters and Months"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 13056, 13311)) then "CJK Compatibility"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 13312, 19903)) then "CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 19904, 19967)) then "Yijing Hexagram Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 19968, 40959)) then "CJK Unified Ideographs"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 40960, 42127)) then "Yi Syllables"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 42128, 42191)) then "Yi Radicals"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 42192, 42239)) then "Lisu"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 42240, 42559)) then "Vai"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 42560, 42655)) then "Cyrillic Extended-B"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 42656, 42751)) then "Bamum"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 42752, 42783)) then "Modifier Tone Letters"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 42784, 43007)) then "Latin Extended-D"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43008, 43055)) then "Syloti Nagri"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43056, 43071)) then "Common Indic Number Forms"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43072, 43135)) then "Phags-pa"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43136, 43231)) then "Saurashtra"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43232, 43263)) then "Devanagari Extended"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43264, 43311)) then "Kayah Li"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43312, 43359)) then "Rejang"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43360, 43391)) then "Hangul Jamo Extended-A"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43392, 43487)) then "Javanese"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43520, 43615)) then "Cham"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43616, 43647)) then "Myanmar Extended-A"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43648, 43743)) then "Tai Viet"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43744, 43775)) then "Meetei Mayek Extensions"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43776, 43823)) then "Ethiopic Extended-A"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 43968, 44031)) then "Meetei Mayek"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 44032, 55215)) then "Hangul Syllables"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 55216, 55295)) then "Hangul Jamo Extended-B"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 55296, 56191)) then "High Surrogates"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 56192, 56319)) then "High Private Use Surrogates"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 56320, 57343)) then "Low Surrogates"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 57344, 63743)) then "Private Use Area"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 63744, 64255)) then "CJK Compatibility Ideographs"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 64256, 64335)) then "Alphabetic Presentation Forms"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 64336, 65023)) then "Arabic Presentation Forms-A"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65024, 65039)) then "Variation Selectors"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65040, 65055)) then "Vertical Forms"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65056, 65071)) then "Combining Half Marks"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65072, 65103)) then "CJK Compatibility Forms"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65104, 65135)) then "Small Form Variants"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65136, 65279)) then "Arabic Presentation Forms-B"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65280, 65519)) then "Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65520, 65535)) then "Specials"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65536, 65663)) then "Linear B Syllabary"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65664, 65791)) then "Linear B Ideograms"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65792, 65855)) then "Aegean Numbers"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65856, 65935)) then "Ancient Greek Numbers"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 65936, 65999)) then "Ancient Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 66000, 66047)) then "Phaistos Disc"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 66176, 66207)) then "Lycian"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 66208, 66271)) then "Carian"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 66304, 66351)) then "Old Italic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 66352, 66383)) then "Gothic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 66432, 66463)) then "Ugaritic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 66464, 66527)) then "Old Persian"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 66560, 66639)) then "Deseret"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 66640, 66687)) then "Shavian"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 66688, 66735)) then "Osmanya"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 67584, 67647)) then "Cypriot Syllabary"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 67648, 67679)) then "Imperial Aramaic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 67840, 67871)) then "Phoenician"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 67872, 67903)) then "Lydian"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 67968, 67999)) then "Meroitic Hieroglyphs"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 68000, 68095)) then "Meroitic Cursive"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 68096, 68191)) then "Kharoshthi"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 68192, 68223)) then "Old South Arabian"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 68352, 68415)) then "Avestan"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 68416, 68447)) then "Inscriptional Parthian"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 68448, 68479)) then "Inscriptional Pahlavi"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 68608, 68687)) then "Old Turkic"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 69216, 69247)) then "Rumi Numeral Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 69632, 69759)) then "Brahmi"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 69760, 69839)) then "Kaithi"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 69840, 69887)) then "Sora Sompeng"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 69888, 69967)) then "Chakma"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 70016, 70111)) then "Sharada"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 71296, 71375)) then "Takri"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 73728, 74751)) then "Cuneiform"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 74752, 74879)) then "Cuneiform Numbers and Punctuation"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 77824, 78895)) then "Egyptian Hieroglyphs"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 92160, 92735)) then "Bamum Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 93952, 94111)) then "Miao"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 110592, 110847)) then "Kana Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 118784, 119039)) then "Byzantine Musical Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 119040, 119295)) then "Musical Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 119296, 119375)) then "Ancient Greek Musical Notation"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 119552, 119647)) then "Tai Xuan Jing Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 119648, 119679)) then "Counting Rod Numerals"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 119808, 120831)) then "Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 126464, 126719)) then "Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 126976, 127023)) then "Mahjong Tiles"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 127024, 127135)) then "Domino Tiles"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 127136, 127231)) then "Playing Cards"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 127232, 127487)) then "Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 127488, 127743)) then "Enclosed Ideographic Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 127744, 128511)) then "Miscellaneous Symbols And Pictographs"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 128512, 128591)) then "Emoticons"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 128640, 128767)) then "Transport And Map Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 128768, 128895)) then "Alchemical Symbols"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 131072, 173791)) then "CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 173824, 177983)) then "CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 177984, 178207)) then "CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 194560, 195103)) then "CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 917504, 917631)) then "Tags"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 917760, 917999)) then "Variation Selectors Supplement"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 983040, 1048575)) then "Supplementary Private Use Area-A"
    else if (functx:between-inclusive($x, 1048576, 1114111)) then "Supplementary Private Use Area-B"
    else()
let $distinct_block-name :=
    for $x in distinct-values($block-name)
    order by $x
    return <block>{$x}</block>

return
    <distinct-blocks distinct-block-count="{count($distinct_block-name)}" distinct-character-count="{count($distinct_character)}">
    {$distinct_block-name}
    </distinct-blocks>
```